# Is there a way to hover over line height in html css?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a hover effect when I hover over a sentence, however the sentence only changes color when I hover over the text, not the space between the lines (line-height). Does anyone know how to fix this?

I've included a sample of what my code looks like, I've removed some classes as i believe its irrelevant.

Thank you~

EDIT: Using inline-block for Span doesn't work because it separates sentences. I'm hoping for it to look like one whole paragraph

[Here is an image of how the hover looks like, when hovering over the sentence it is white, but hovering over the lines makes it grey again. This creates a really glitchy effect which i don't want. Anywhere red is where the hover effect doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYuxE.png)

```css
#text-hover {
  color: var(--grey);
}

#text-hover:hover {
  color: var(--white);
}
```

```html
<h2>
  <span id="text-hover">I'm a student from Vancouver, Canada, currently studying interaction design at Simon Fraser University.</span>
  <span id="text-hover">My design practices include UX, UI, interaction and visual design. I aim to understand people’s motivations, needs and behaviours to help create meaningful and purposeful interventions.</span>
  <span id="text-hover">During my free time, I like to build in Minecraft, draw, participate in design challenges and daydream.</span>
</h2>
```

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Comment: Also all that text inside an <h2> is bad practice. H2 is meant for titles (that's what engines expect), for big chunks of text use <p>

Answer (score 1):

With span tags the element doesn't include the line height. If you use a div tag and then target the hover effect to the parent div it should do what you're after.

p.s. also ID's should only be used once. if using the same styling on multiple elements you should use classes which I've changed it to below.

```css
h2 {line-height:4;}

.text-hover div {
  color: grey;
  background:black;
}

.text-hover div:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="text-hover">
  <div>I'm a student from Vancouver, Canada, currently studying interaction design at Simon Fraser University.</div>
  <div>My design practices include UX, UI, interaction and visual design. I aim to understand people’s motivations, needs and behaviours to help create meaningful and purposeful interventions.</div>
  <div>During my free time, I like to build in Minecraft, draw, participate in design challenges and daydream.</div>
</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need. Anyway, use the ID only 1 time per page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
        h2 {
            color: black;
        }

        h2:hover .text-hover {
            color: green;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>
    <span class="text-hover">I'm a student from Vancouver, Canada, currently studying interaction design at Simon Fraser University.</span>
    <span class="text-hover">My design practices include UX, UI, interaction and visual design. I aim to understand people’s motivations, needs and behaviours to help create meaningful and purposeful interventions.</span>
    <span class="text-hover">During my free time, I like to build in Minecraft, draw, participate in design challenges and daydream.</span>
</h2>

</body>
</html>
```